# Angular 2 - how to fill a local variable with JSON data from an external file

Tags: json, angular

The Angular 2 tutorials I have read place variables directly in the app.component.ts file. For example `var BAR` below, which pulls data though the `{Foo}` interface.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Foo} from './foo';

@Component({
   etc.
});

export class AppComponent {
   bar = BAR;
}

var BAR: Foo[] = [
   { 'id': 1 },
   { 'id': 2 }
];
```

However, I have the data for BAR in a local JSON file. I don't believe {HTTP_PROVIDER} is necessary. How would I go about getting the JSON data from the external file?

Answer (score 13):

Create a file  with this content

`export const BAR= [
   { 'id': 1 },
   { 'id': 2 }
];`

save it as `BarConfig.ts` or some like

later use it as follows

`import { BAR } from './BarConfig';
let bar= BAR;`

or even better, use `BAR` directly where you needed

Comment: He is asking for importing json data from local file and not a class.

Comment: @FlorianLeitgeb Is not a [class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) it's a declaration being export [(See Export)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) in this case a constant (from [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html) to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)). You can use a variable instead constant if you want.

Comment: @WilliamArdila I tried this way and it's working. So is this a good way to use global configurations? (eg: keep the image folder path in a constant and use everywhere )

Comment: @HashanKanchana Little bit offtopic: About configurations see [this](https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/angular-2-and-environment-variables-59c57ba643be)

Answer (score 5):

`HTTP_PROVIDER` is needed if you want to load a file using http.

Here is an example of how to load a local json file over http:

```
this.result = {friends:[]};
this.http.get('./friends.json').map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(res => this.result = res);
```

More details here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-and-http

Comment: The question was : How do we do that WITHOUT using http?

Answer (score 4):

Juste put your .json file in your static folder (/assets if you are using the angular cli) and it should work.

Comment: How do you mean work, though? Will it get loaded into the scope somehow?

Comment: Thanks.. This works..  When you do this be sure to reference the assets folder in your url. e.g: fetch("assets/data.json").then(...)

Comment: Need more explanation for your solution

Answer (score 3):

Best option is to create json file and store json details inside file and call that file using like below.

If you using angular-cli Keep the json file inside Assets folder (parallel to app dir) directory

```
return this.http.get('<json file path inside assets folder>.json'))
    .map((response: Response) => {
        console.log("mock data" + response.json());
        return response.json();
    }
    )
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Note: here you only need to give path inside assets folder like assets/json/oldjson.json then you need to write path like /json/oldjson.json

If you using webpack then you need to follow above same structure inside public folder its similar like assets folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Http** provider in angular2

Make sure you **place your local json file in the www folder.**

```
getLocalFile(){
    return this.http.get('./localFileName.json').
        map(res => res.json());
}
```

This will return you the local JSON file.

Comment: This is actually returning an Observable and not the data as object